# invalid argument supplied for foreach() php

Tags: php, foreach

i have index.php and index2.php

here is index.php:

[image]

when i submit this value, index2.php will show. Here is index2.php:

[image]

I am not understanding, why this error msg is showing.

Anyways, submitting these selected values(index2.php) it will say a disease name from the database. clicking on submit, this text is showing(below):

[image]

I am pesting my code here:

#### index.php

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("symptomchecker",$con) or die(mysql_error());

$q = "select dtid,diseasetype from disease_type";

$result = mysql_query($q,$con) or die(mysql_error());

$numRB = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "<html><head><title>Disease Type</title></head><body><h1>Disease List</h1></br><form action='index2.php' method='post'>";

$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['diseasetype'];
    echo "<input type='radio' name='diseasetype' id='pet1' value='$row[dtid]' />" ;
    echo "<br />";
    $i++;
}
echo " <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'></form></body></html>";
?>
```

#### index2.php:

> ```
> $diseasetypeid = "$_POST[diseasetype]";
>
> $j=0;$i=0;
> $query = "select did from disty_dis_rel where dtid = ".$diseasetypeid."";
> $result1 = mysql_query($query,$con) or die(mysql_error());
> echo "<html><head><title>symptom</title></head><body><h1>symptom List</h1></br><form action='' method='post'>";
>
> while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($result1))
> {
>   $z=$row['did'];
>   $query2 = "select sid,symptomname from symptom where sid = ".$z."";
>   $result2 =  mysql_query($query2,$con) or die(mysql_error());
>   while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
>   {
>       echo $row2['symptomname'];
>       echo "<input type='checkbox' name='pets[$i]' id='pet1' value='$row[sid]' />" ;
>       echo "<br />";
>       $i++;
>       }
>   $j++;
>   }
> echo " <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'></form></body></html>";
>
>
> if(isset($_REQUEST[submit]))
> {
>   **foreach ($_REQUEST[pets] as $key=>$values)**
>   {
>       $yy.=$values."-";
>   }
>   $yy=rtrim($yy,"-");
>
>   $xx = "select did,sids from dis_sym_rel where sids=".$yy."";
>   $result3 = mysql_query($xx,$con) or die(mysql_error());
>
>   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
>       $p=$row[did];
>       $xxx = "select did,diseasename from disease where did=".$p."";
>       $result4 = mysql_query($xxx,$con) or die(mysql_error());
>       while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4))
>       {
>           echo $row4[diseasename];    
>       }
>   }
> }
> ?>
> ```

the line between ###doublestar### is the error line(49).

Comment: learn to abuse [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just within `index2.php` :

```
$diseasetypeid = "$_POST[diseasetype]";
```

should be

```
$diseasetypeid = $_POST["diseasetype"];
```

and

```
if(isset($_REQUEST[submit]))
```

should really be this :

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

this checks the REQUEST_METHOD rather than a form value. And

```
foreach ($_REQUEST[pets] as $key=>$values)
```

should be

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['pets'] as $key=>$values)
```

and I suggest you read about [sql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: @decoyer add some simple debugging to check the values of variables before using them in `if` statements and `foreach` loops

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST[pets] as $key=>$values)
```

Should be changed to:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['pets'] as $key=>$values)
```

You should quote (put apostrophe or double-quotes, before and after your array key if it's string).

Then, you must have a form something to the following (i can't find it in your index.php file).

```
<input type="text" name="pets[]" />
<input type="text" name="pets[]" />
<input type="text" name="pets[]" />
<input type="text" name="pets[]" />
<input type="text" name="pets[]" />
```

The array key 'pets' is the name of your input. [] indicates array. In foreach ($something as ...), $something must be an array (or object).